# Displaying a tooltip when user hovers on label of radio button in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, zend-form

I have some radio buttons in a form:

```
<div id="data_id-block">
<dt id="data_id-label"><label class="required">Data</label></dt>
<dd id="data_id-element">
    <label for="data_id-1">
        <input type="radio" name="data_id" id="data_id-1" value="1" />test 1
    </label><br />
    <label for="data_id-2">
        <input type="radio" name="data_id" id="data_id-2" value="2" />test 2
    </label><br />
    <label for="data_id-4">
        <input type="radio" name="data_id" id="data_id-4" value="4" /> Test Data
    </label><br />
    <label for="data_id-5">
        <input type="radio" name="data_id" id="data_id-5" value="5" /> Second Test Data
    </label><br />
    <label for="data_id-6">
        <input type="radio" name="data_id" id="data_id-6" value="6" />Unassigned
    </label>
</dd>
```

I'm trying to display a tooltip when a user hovers over the label of the radio button. I can do this but I also want to get whatever is in the 'value' property of the radio button. My attempts to this resulted in only the 'value' of the radio button being returned regardless of which radio button was hovered over.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you show the code you're currently using to attempt retrieving the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//this is just one way to register to the window.onLoad event in jQuery, i prefer it's readability for what is going on    
$(document).ready(function(){
//$("something", "something else") - 'Something Else' limits where jQuery searches for 'something'
// .hover( function A , function B ) - function A is the mouseover event, function B is the mouseleave event
// function(event){}  for All events, jQuery will always pass an "event" parameter if you ask for it on the window .event() registration.  cool stuff you can do with jQuery's "event" parameter can be found here in the references below.
      $("label", "#data_id-element").hover(function(event){
// $(this)  jQuery'itize the html Element the user hovered into 
// .attr("for") - get the value of the 'for' attribute
// $("#" + whatever) - get whatever this is by its id='' attribute
// .val()  - get the value of whatever this is
         var radioValue = $("#"+$(this).attr("for")).val();
      }, 
      function(event){
// $(this)  jQuery'itize the html Element the user hovered out of
// .attr("for") - get the value of the 'for' attribute
// $("#" + whatever) - get whatever this is by its id='' attribute
// .val()  - get the value of whatever this is
        var radioValue = $("#"+$(this).attr("for")).val();
      });

    });
```

Comment: this code uses the <label for=''> value to lookup that radio checkbox.  This means it does not depend upon the structure of the html, just that your 'for' attribute value is accurate.

Comment: Thanks this works, but can you explain the code from "function(event){.." onwards pls?

Comment: more notes than you can shake a stick at ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, you want to get the value of the radio button associated with a `label`, when you hover over the `label`. If that's the case, try something like this:

```
$("label").mouseover(function() {
    var radioButtonValue = $(this).find("input").val(); 
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/L7NRb/).

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. I looked at the example but nothing is logged to the console...

Comment: @Sid - In which example? The link posted in my answer definitely logs the values to my console! In the link posted by HerrSerker in the comments, the value is used as a `title` attribute.

Comment: In both examples, I clicked on the link then hovered over the labels and checked the console using firebug but nothing was there. Obviously something wrong with my set up or the way I'm checking it.