# JQuery Tooltip Hover on Radio Button

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button, tooltip, tipsy

I want to have a tooltip show on hover over a radio button. So I'm trying to use this plugin: [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/). So here's my html:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="options" value="1" class="required" id="option1"> Option1</label>
```

And then I tried something like this:

```
$("#option1").tipsy({fallback: "test" });
```

But when i hovered over the radio button, nothing appeared. Why isn't anything appearing and how do I make it work?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838646/displaying-a-tooltip-when-user-hovers-on-label-of-radio-button-in-jquery

Answer (score 6):

Add `title` to your `input`.

`<input type="radio" name="options" value="1" class="required" id="option1" title="MyText">`

Comment: For somereason this displays text at the top of my page rather than right next to the radio button like a normal tooltip. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you could approach a hover-over. It's fairly simple...

http://jsfiddle.net/wrN2u/50/

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting the text in the title attribute?

```
<input type="radio" name="options" value="1" title="Some Text To Display" class="required" id="option1" />
```